# Column not showing data using Gridjs while integrating with React js

Tags: reactjs, html-table, datatable, datafield, gridjs

currently I am using Gridjs to display my table in my Reactjs application.

[image]

This is the code, the **Name**, and **Email** is displaying correctly, but the **created_at** is not, giving me empty. How can I display the data? thank you..

Answer (score 3):

You need to define a custom `id` for your column if you're using a JSON input.

Example:

```js
const grid = new Grid({
  columns: [{
     id: 'name',
     name: 'Name'
  }, {
     id: 'email',
     name: 'Email'
  }, {
     id: 'phoneNumber',
     name: 'Phone Number'
  }],
  data: [
    { name: 'John', email: 'john@example.com', phoneNumber: '(353) 01 222 3333' },
    { name: 'Mark', email: 'mark@gmail.com', phoneNumber: '(01) 22 888 4444' },
  ]
});
```

See https://gridjs.io/docs/examples/import-json/

Comment: To elaborate, the **value** of the key id in "columns" needs to be the same as the name of the **key** in "data".

Comment: gridjs sure takes camelCase/case sensitive seriously.